# ob_get_contents doesnt work when within foreach

Tags: foreach, ob-get-contents

Hi,

I have this code which works just fine

```
function show_aval($place) {
   echo $place;
}

ob_start();
show_aval(london);
$show_aval = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
show_aval(york);
$show_aval2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

ob_start();
show_aval(liverpool);
$show_aval3 = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
```

but I want to simplify this code like this:

```
$avalrooms = [];
$cities = ["london", "york", "liverpool"];
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    ob_start();
    show_aval($city);
    $avalrooms[$city] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean;
}
```

however, this seems to nullify `ob_get_contents` because the function is being executed right away as `show_aval($city);` is stated.

Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Typo `ob_clean;`? Also, check out [`ob_get_clean`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), dont need to clean up then.

Comment: I dont see any typo in my code.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `ob_clean();`  https://3v4l.org/rTWg8

Comment: Though why are you using ob_ functions, you should only need them for the most part if you're building a templating system, and want to render in variables html etc, but then you add the ob_ calls inside the function.